# Is JSOM also security trimmed like rest is?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, security-trimming

In sharepoint 2010/2013, I know REST api is automatically security trimmed, but is the JSOM (javascript object model) also security trimmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are both security trimmed, there is no impersonation or elevation of privilege available in these APIs.

Answer (score 1):

JSOM (and REST API) runs in the context of the user querying the endpoint or execute the code on the client side. Therefore it is security trimmed.

Comment: typo, it should be JSOM*